# What insect is this with 'horn' at the side?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this interesting insect hiding behind the thin branch of flower (the diameter of the branch is 3-4mm) in my garden in Kuching, Sarawak, Malaysia

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Karl Kjer It's most likely a *Leptocentrus taurus*, even though the perspective in the photo doesn't allow to observe the prominent dorsal thorn.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/some_soul/15316794326

https://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/list?count=0&hasMore=true&max=10&offset=0&sort=lastrevised&taxon=72846&view=list

Ants are always trying to come in contact with these mimic treehoppers for collecting the sweet juices secreted by them. Maybe the OP can confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

That is a treehopper. Order Hemptera, family Membracidae. I looked on a site for membracids of Malaysia, and could not bring it to species-level. But I am confident that it is a membracid. This family is characterized by sometimes bizarre protrusions of the pronotum. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehopper